# ArcGIS JavaScript API Buffer Units from Dropdown

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, buffer, geometry-service

I am trying to create a buffer that will have the distance and units inputted by the user.

[image: This is what displays on my program.]

I'm having trouble getting the JavaScript to recognize the which Unit of Measurement the buffer is being set to. When I click on the map to generate the buffer nothing shows up. This is the JavaScript I wrote:

```
function doBuffer(evt) {
            map.graphics.clear();
            var params = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
            params.geometries = [ evt.mapPoint ];

          //buffer in linear units such as meters, km, miles etc.
            params.distances = [ document.getElementById("distance").value];
            params.unit = document.getElementById("units").value;
            params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;

            gsvc.buffer(params, showBuffer);
        }
```

This is the HTML I wrote:

```
 <div id="featureCount">Enter the unit and distance to set the buffer.</div>
                <p>Distance</p>
                <input id="distance" type="number" name="Distance">
                <p>Unit of Measurement</p>
                <select id="units">
                    <option value="esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_FOOT">Feet (ft)</option>
                    <option value="esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_METER">Meters (m)</option>
                    <option value="esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_KILOMETER">Kilometers (km)</option>
                    <option value="esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_STATUTE_MILE">Miles (mi)</option>
                    <option value="esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_NAUTICAL_MILE">Nautical Miles (NM)</option>
                </select>
```

How can I get my code to recognize which unit of measurement I am setting the buffer to so it can load correctly?

Comment: Without writing out a lot of JS to be sure, try: `params.unit = document.getElementById("units").options[document.getElementById("units").selectedIndex].value;`  reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: @KHibma I put this into my code and it did not work. Thank you for trying to help though!

Comment: It might be your option value. Not sure that you need to pass esri.task..... in. Per the help doc pointing to this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#/esriSRUnitType_Constants/000w00000042000000/  - it seems to suggest using the value. So unit foot is actually a value of 9002

Comment: Compare your code with this [sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=util_buffergraphic), which has the same sort of dropdown box for units. Also, are you seeing any messages in the console?

Comment: @kenbuja That's actually what I was using to write my code, and no I am not receiving any messages in the console.

Comment: @KHibma I tried using the values from the second link and it was able to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unit type for the geometry service accepts the code value.
The code value can be found on the [esriSRUnitType Constants](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#/esriSRUnitType_Constants/000w00000042000000/) page.

For example, if you want `esriSRUnit_Meter`, you can provide the value `9001`